# Run Docker Containers on an Existing Kubernetes Cluster on Palantir Foundry

Tags: palantir-foundry, palantir-foundry-api, palantir-foundry-security

I have a deep question that I couldn't find an answer on the Palantir Foundry documentation. The question is: Can I define a workflow in Palantir such that each step in this workflow uses Docker image to run inside my existing on-premises Kubernetes cluster?

I have tried exploring the documentation of the Palantir Foundry platform but I couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Can you please provide some more context - 1. How do you want to interact with the docker images? 2. Is the on-premises k8s cluster a Foundry cluster or a self-managed cluster? 

Any more information about the workflow will help get your question answered